Edit the opacity of an image in rust
I am trying to loop over a directory of images, edit the opacity to 50%, and then save them. I have a collection of images that are jpg and png. I am using the image crate.
Probably I have to make some considerations about the formats of the images, but I don't know what...
use clap::Parser;
use std::{process, thread};
#[derive(Parser,Debug)]
#[command(author,version,about,long_about=None)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(long,value_hint=clap::ValueHint::DirPath, default_value="./")]
    picture_dir: std::path::PathBuf,
    #[arg(long, default_value="300")]
    draw_time: u64,
    #[arg(long, default_value="3")]
    start_delay: u64,
    #[arg(long)]
    dry_run: bool,
}


fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
    println!("{}", args.picture_dir.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap());
    let dir = args.picture_dir.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap();
    let dir = format!("{}/*.*", dir);
    let extensions_supported = vec!("png","jpg","bmp");
    for path in glob::glob(&dir).expect("Failed to list directory") {
        let path = path.unwrap();
        let copy_from_path = path.clone();
        let file_name = path.file_name().unwrap();
        let mut cachepath = std::env::temp_dir();
        cachepath.push(file_name.to_str().unwrap());
        let str_path = cachepath.to_str().unwrap();
        let path_extension = path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
        if !extensions_supported.contains(&path_extension) {
            println!("We don't support that file type");
            continue;
        }
        println!("{}", str_path);
        let start = std::time::Instant::now();
        // We should open the program
        let cmd_str = format!("cmd.exe /C clipstudiopaint.exe {}", str_path);
        let mut child: Option<process::Child> = None;
        if args.dry_run {
            println!("{}",cmd_str);
        } else {
            std::fs::copy(copy_from_path,cachepath.clone()).expect("Failed to create temporary file");
            let cache_image_path = cachepath.clone();
            let cache_image_path = cache_image_path.to_str().unwrap();
            let save_image_path = cachepath.clone();
            let mut image = image::open(cache_image_path)
            .expect("Failed to open image for editing").to_rgba32f();
            image.pixels_mut().for_each(|p| p[3] /= 2.0);
            
            image.save(save_image_path.to_str().unwrap()).expect("Failed to save image");
            //let mut image_target = image::ImageBuffer::new(image.width(), image.height());
            child = Some(process::Command::new("cmd")
            .arg("/C")
            .arg("clipstudiopaint.exe")
            .arg(cachepath.to_str().unwrap())
            .spawn()
            .expect("Failed to run clipstudiopaint"));
        }
        // We should wait a couple of seconds for it to load
        loop {
            if start.elapsed().as_secs() > args.start_delay {
                break;
            }
        }
        let start = std::time::Instant::now();
        // we should wait the specified drawing time
        println!("Starting timer");
        loop {
            if start.elapsed().as_secs() > args.draw_time {
                break;
            }
        }   
        // we should kill the process
        if !args.dry_run {
            child.unwrap().kill().expect("Failed to kill childprocess");
            std::fs::remove_file(cachepath).expect("Failed to remove temp file");
        }
        let start = std::time::Instant::now();
        loop {
            if start.elapsed().as_secs() > 2 {
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}


This leads to the error: Failed to save image: Encoding(EncodingError { format: Exact(Png), underlying: Some(ColorType(Rgba32F)) })
The relevant bits of the final answer ended up looking like this:
std::fs::copy(copy_from_path,cachepath.clone()).expect("Failed to create temporary file");
let image_edit_path = image_edit_path.clone();
let image_edit_path = image_edit_path.to_str().unwrap();
let save_image_path = cachepath.clone();
println!("Opening: {} for editing", image_edit_path);
let mut image = image::open(image_edit_path)
.expect("Failed to open image for editing");
let mut target_image = image::DynamicImage::new_rgba8(image.width(), image.height());
let mut target_image = target_image.to_rgba8();
target_image.pixels_mut().for_each(|p| *p = image::Rgba{0: [246, 244, 237, 255]});
let mut image = image.to_rgba8();
image.pixels_mut().for_each(|p| p[3] = 100);
image::imageops::overlay(&mut target_image, &image, 0, 0);
let target_image = image::DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(target_image);

target_image.save(save_image_path.to_str().unwrap()).expect("Failed to save image");


You realize you don't need to .as_str() your PathBuf ot pass it to save or open etc? They all take impl AsRef<Path> meaning they can work with &str, String, PathBuf, &Path and more directly.

Not all encoders support all color formats.
Since you're explicitly converting it using to_rgba32f(), then you equally have to convert it back into a format, that is supported by the encoder you're using. For PNG use e.g. to_rgba8() or into_rgba8().
let image = image.into_rgba8();

image.save(...)...

For JPEG, well, you'll have to save them as (e.g.) PNGs as well, if you want transparency.
Otherwise when you attempt to save it, you'll similarly get an encoding error, as JPEG doesn't support an alpha channel. (At least the image crate encoder does not.)

To be completely pedantic, the JPEG format itself supports an "alpha" channel. But this isn't used, nor widely supported, and it specifically isn't supported by the image crate. See Q2639866 for more information.

You're a genius. Though actually I had to do one more thing, that is load the images, and work in Rgba8 entirely.
